# How to Draw boxes in Plain TEX?

Tags: boxes

I study plain TEX and i need a way to draw a frame around each hbox and vbox in order to undestand how TEX works .. is it possible to do this? thanks !

Comment: I found this question but it uses \fbox and LaTEX functionality .. i need a similar command for plain TEX

Comment: @Sigur Isn't the duplicate about *glyph* boxes and not `\hbox` and `\vbox` in general?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, you are right. I simply saw there some rectangles around the whole text and I misunderstood.

Comment: I don’t have the file to hand right now, but if you look in Knuth’s “The TeXbook”, in one of the chapters (I think its called “boxes”) there is an exercise which asks the reader to do this, which will have an answer in Appendix A